# How do I handle Request Body Error in Ktor

Tags: postman, ktor, kotlinx.serialization

I am new to Ktor and I have a route with a request body which i am parsing with Kotlin Serialization.

I know that the request body is expected to conform to the request body data class but then, I tested by passing the wrong field in my test payload and it crashed the app.

I want to be able to handle such scenarios and respond to the client that such a field is not allowed. How do i go about that.

This is my sample data class:

```
@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
data class UserLoginDetails(
    var email: String = "",
    var password: String = ""
)
```

This is the route:

```
post("/user/login") {
   val userInfo  = call.receive<UserLoginDetails>()
   //my code here
}
```

The payload below works

```
{
   "email": "test@email.com",
   "password": "password"
}
```

But if use an alternative payload for instance:

```
{
    "phone": "test@email.com",
    "password": "password"
}
```

The app crashes with the crash message:

> kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Unexpected
> JSON token at offset 7: Encountered an unknown key 'emai'. Use
> 'ignoreUnknownKeys = true' in 'Json {}' builder to ignore unknown
> keys.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options in Ktor:

1. `call.receive` is the function which can throw an exception in this case, you can simply catch it:

```
try {
    val userInfo = call.receive<UserLoginDetails>()
} catch (t: Throwable) {
    // handle error
}
```

2. Catching exceptions globally using [Status Pages](https://ktor.io/docs/status-pages.html#exceptions):

```
install(StatusPages) {
    exception<SerializationException> { cause ->
        call.respond(/* */)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says you can setup your Json with the config `ignoreUnknownKeys = true` where you are creating the Json object. [Here's the doc link](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#ignoring-unknown-keys).

a tip: You might also want to check other configuration options so you can avoid setting empty string as default values.